# Faster way to search for dates in numpy array of datetime.date objects?

Tags: python, search, datetime, numpy

I have a large, chronologically ordered array of datetime.date objects. Many of the dates in this array are the same, however some dates are missing... (it's a time series of 'real data', so it's messy).

I want to count how many data points there are for each date, currently I do it like this:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

t = np.array([dt.date(2012,12,1) + dt.timedelta(n) for n in np.arange(0,31,0.25)])

Ndays = (t[-1] - t[0]).days

data_per_day = np.array([sum(t == t[0] + dt.timedelta(d)) for d in xrange(Ndays)])
```

However I find this to be very slow! (More than 10 minutes for approximately 400,000 data points) Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: maybe the call to `timedelta` is slowing you down. Consider comparing `d` with `tLen = t-t[0]`, which you compute before instead? How big is `Ndays` when you have 400k dates?

Comment: The performance of the different proposed solution differs greatly depending on how many days you have. For the 400000 data points, what is het value of `Ndays`?

Comment: `Ndays` is of order 2000. The solution by @root below speeded things up by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: JesseC, out of curiosity, did you compare with my method?

Comment: Okay, I just tried, and @root's method is 14 times *slower* than my method if you include the time to convert data types. If you don't count that bit, then his method is about 4 times *faster* than mine. (This test is done on `200000` dates spanning `2000` days.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.datetime64`. On the data *@Hans Then* I get 241 ms.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import datetime as dt

In [3]: t = np.array([dt.date(2012,12,1) + dt.timedelta(n)
                        for n in np.arange(0,31,0.00001)])

In [4]: t = t.astype(np.datetime64)

In [5]: daterange = np.arange(t[0], t[-1], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [6]: np.bincount(daterange.searchsorted(t))
Out[6]: 
array([100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000,
       100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000,
       100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000,
       100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000])

In [7]: %timeit np.bincount(daterange.searchsorted(t))
1 loops, best of 3: 241 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is pretty nice. I think your bottleneck for real data will be the call to `searchsorted`

Comment: @Geoff -- Without knowing the characteristics of the real data it is really almost impossible to tell...

Comment: Amazing, thanks, this speeded things up mightily. Only slight issue is that `daterange = np.arange(t[0], t[-1], dtype='datetime64[D]')` gives me the following error:

`TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'` 

(But I found a workaround)

Comment: @JesseC -- What does `np.__version__` say? Perhaps you are using an older version of `numpy`... An upgrade to the latest should fix that.

Comment: Mine says `1.6.2` and gives that error. What version is needed, root?

Comment: I just got it. Your code is super fast, the bottleneck (for Hans's data, and for random data) comes from the conversion to datetime64. I posted timing results as a comment above.

Comment: @Geoff -- yes, the conversion is slow, but it's hardly ever needed to convert it to datetime in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

This runs in a couple of seconds for 3,100,000 entries.

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

t = np.array([dt.date(2012,12,1) + dt.timedelta(n) for n in np.arange(0,31,0.00001)])

c = Counter(t)
print c
```

Comment: And how fast with numpy? Because for me, the method given by the OP also takes only 2-3 seconds with these data.

Comment: I didn't check. I just wanted the show how cool the Counter class is. Using numpy's datetime64 is the better solution, so I will upvote that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on detecting the distance between unique dates

```
# Get the unique day indexes of t
indexes = np.hstack(([-1], np.nonzero(np.diff(t))[0], [len(t)-1]))
# Determine how many data points are for that day
lengths = np.hstack(np.diff(indexes))

# Pull out the actual dates for the new days
dates = t[indexes[:-1] +1]
# Convert them to indexes (or day offsets)
as_int = np.vectorize(lambda d : d.day)(dates) -1

# Make a np array of these lengths
data_per_day = np.zeros((Ndays + 1,), np.int)
data_per_day[as_int] = lengths
```